# Can't add document from Firestore API. Error 400 Resource name ... lacks \"projects\" at index 0

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-api

I try to add one document from Firestore API Explorer.

This is the data i try to insert:

```
POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myProjetID/databases/(default)/documents/myCollection/2019/04?documentId=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "fields": {
  "field0": {
   "referenceValue": "ref0"
  }
 }
}
```

I'm having this error:

```
cache-control:  private
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  143
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Mon, 08 Apr 2019 09:24:09 GMT
server:  ESF
vary:  Origin, X-Origin, Referer

{
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Resource name \"ref0\" lacks \"projects\" at index 0.",
  "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because, with `"referenceValue"`, you try to write the value of a field of type **Reference**, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types

You need to specify the full path of the reference (i.e. the full Document path), as follows:

```
{
 "fields": {
  "name": {
   "referenceValue": "projects/{myProjetID}/databases/(default)/documents/{collectionName}/{documentId}"
  }
 }
}
```

It will be saved in the database as `/{collectionName}/{documentId}`

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to execute the export statement of `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST` variable printed when I started the firestore emulator.

For eg,

```
export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=[::1]:8647
```