# Firestore REST API batchGet returns status 400

Tags: firebase, api, rest, google-cloud-firestore, appgyver

I am trying to get data from Firestore in a batch using the [batchGet](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/batchGet) method. But i get an error as below :

> Error: JSON error response from server: [{"error":{"code":400,"message":"Document name "["projects/MYPROJECT/databases/(default)/documents/MYCOLLECTION/DOCUMENTID"]" lacks "projects" at index 0.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}].status: 400

I have searched for any questions regarding this, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570786/cant-add-document-from-firestore-api-error-400-resource-name-lacks-proje). They are trying t add documents and not using batchGet, however I have followed the solution. Still no luck.

**Note: I am integrating Firebase to AppGyver.**

I am new to Firebase and still learning. I need all the help I can get. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what I did wrong.

In AppGyver you can only set your parameters as `text` or `number` only. While the `documents` parameter needs to be in array. Hence, I convert the array to string using `ENCODE_JSON`. But that was wrong.

The correct way is just send the `documents` in array without converting it. Use the formula :

[image: AppGyver binding]

Just hit "Save" even there is an error telling you that it is not a text.